# VBA to check if mutiple ranges are blank and enter data if first cell of each range that is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to look at 6 specific ranges:

("F15:F4999")
("H15:H4999")
("J15:J4999")
("L15:L4999")
("N15:N4999")
("P15:P4999")

If one or more of these ranges is blank, I need the macro to enter "No Data" in the first cell of the blank range(s) (*i.e. in F15*). The ranges contain various types of data to include text, dollar values, dates, and percentages.

This macro will be part of it's own module, and will be called at the end of another macro.

I have tried using the COUNTA function, but get hung up due to type mismatch errors. The following works, but only for the first blank range each time I run it. (*i.e. if column F is blank, it will enter "No Data", but will not continue on and enter "No Data in blank columns that follow*)

```
Sub FillFetchDataBlanks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheets("Graph Data").Select

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F15:F4999")) <= 0 Then
[F15] = "No Data"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H15:H4999")) <= 0 Then
[H15] = "No Data"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J15:J4999")) <= 0 Then
[J15] = "No Data"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("L15:L4999")) <= 0 Then
[L15] = "No Data"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("N15:N4999")) <= 0 Then
[N15] = "No Data"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("P15:P4999")) <= 0 Then
[P15] = "No Data"

Else

On Error Resume Next


End If

[b15].Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any help and/or advice is appreciated!

Thank you,

John

Comment: use separate Ifs i.e do not combine them using elsif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use separate `Ifs` i.e do not combine them using `ElseIf`.

Try this

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    If .CountA(Range("F15:F4999")) <= 0 Then [F15] = "No Data"
    If .CountA(Range("H15:H4999")) <= 0 Then [H15] = "No Data"
    If .CountA(Range("J15:J4999")) <= 0 Then [J15] = "No Data"
    If .CountA(Range("L15:L4999")) <= 0 Then [L15] = "No Data"
    If .CountA(Range("N15:N4999")) <= 0 Then [N15] = "No Data"
    If .CountA(Range("P15:P4999")) <= 0 Then [P15] = "No Data"
End With
```

This way you also don't need an `Else` and `End If`